# Extracting java script ( / geo json ? ) with BeautifulSoup

Tags: javascript, java, json, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract some java script from TripAdvisor to find some geoInfo codes that they use in order to find some restaurants in different towns.

To do this I want to visit a few pages and scrape the geoName and parentName from the following bit of the page:

```
geoInfo: {
geoId: 31743,                         geoName: `'London',                         parentName: 'United `States',                         shortParentName: 'United States',
```

I am using BeautifulSoup because I have used it with great success for other projects, but I'm struggling to get these variables out.

The code above sits inside a  tag on a geo search page, e.g.:

https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Search?geo=31743

I've tried stuff like, for example:

```
parentname = soup.findAll('script', {'geoInfo': 'parentName'}).string
```

...but with no luck on any variation, just can't seem to get it out of the page.

Any help very much appreciated!

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it! Like so with regular expressions:

```
    find_name = re.search('geoName:(\s\').+?(?=\')', str(soup))
    geoName = find_name.group(0)
```